# 50 minute difference between batch time and submission time in spark streaming

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

spark version is 2.2.0
pseudocode:

read data1 from kafka with 5minute window

read data2 from kafka with 10minute window and 5miute slide duration

data1 join data2 on some condition

do some agg and write to mysql

question:
 batch time is 15:00 but submitted time is 15:50, processing time is less than 1 minute. what happened?

```scala
val shareDs = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String](streamContext, LocationStrategies.PreferBrokers, shareReqConsumer)

val shareResDS = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String](streamContext, LocationStrategies.PreferBrokers, shareResConsumer).window(Minutes(WindowTime), Minutes(StreamTime))

shareDs doSomeMap join (shareResDs doSomeMap) forEachRddd{do some things then write to mysql}
```

[image]
[image]

there are some logs:

```
19/07/22 11:20:00 INFO dstream.MappedDStream: Slicing from 1563765000000 ms to 1563765600000 ms (aligned to 1563765000000 ms and 1563765600000 ms)
19/07/22 11:20:00 INFO dstream.MappedDStream: Slicing from 1563765000000 ms to 1563765600000 ms (aligned to 1563765000000 ms and 1563765600000 ms)
19/07/22 11:20:00 INFO dstream.MappedDStream: Slicing from 1563765000000 ms to 1563765600000 ms (aligned to 1563765000000 ms and 1563765600000 ms)
19/07/22 11:20:00 INFO internals.ConsumerCoordinator: [Consumer clientId=consumer-6, groupId=dashboard] Revoking previously assigned partitions [topic_wh_sparkstream_afp_com_input_result-2, topic_wh_sparkstream_afp_com_input_result-1, topic_wh_sparkstream_afp_com_input_result-0]
19/07/22 11:20:00 INFO internals.AbstractCoordinator: [Consumer clientId=consumer-6, groupId=dashboard] (Re-)joining group
19/07/22 11:25:00 INFO internals.AbstractCoordinator: [Consumer clientId=consumer-6, groupId=dashboard] Successfully joined group with generation 820
19/07/22 11:25:00 INFO internals.ConsumerCoordinator: [Consumer clientId=consumer-6, groupId=dashboard] Setting newly assigned partitions [topic_wh_sparkstream_afp_com_input_result-2, topic_wh_sparkstream_afp_com_input_result-1, topic_wh_sparkstream_afp_com_input_result-0]
19/07/22 11:25:00 INFO dstream.MappedDStream: Slicing from 1563765000000 ms to 1563765600000 ms (aligned to 1563765000000 ms and 1563765600000 ms)
19/07/22 11:25:00 INFO dstream.MappedDStream: Slicing from 1563765000000 ms to 1563765600000 ms (aligned to 1563765000000 ms and 1563765600000 ms)
19/07/22 11:25:00 INFO internals.ConsumerCoordinator: [Consumer clientId=consumer-5, groupId=dashboard] Revoking previously assigned partitions [topic_wh_sparkstream_decision_report_result-1, topic_wh_sparkstream_decision_report_result-2, topic_wh_sparkstream_decision_report_result-0]
19/07/22 11:25:00 INFO internals.AbstractCoordinator: [Consumer clientId=consumer-5, groupId=dashboard] (Re-)joining group
19/07/22 11:30:00 INFO internals.AbstractCoordinator: [Consumer clientId=consumer-5, groupId=dashboard] Successfully joined group with generation 821
19/07/22 11:30:00 INFO internals.ConsumerCoordinator: [Consumer clientId=consumer-5, groupId=dashboard] Setting newly assigned partitions [topic_wh_sparkstream_decision_report_result-1, topic_wh_sparkstream_decision_report_result-2, topic_wh_sparkstream_decision_report_result-0]
19/07/22 11:30:00 INFO internals.ConsumerCoordinator: [Consumer clientId=consumer-4, groupId=dashboard] Revoking previously assigned partitions [topic_wh_sparkstream_echo_mixed_risk_record-1, topic_wh_sparkstream_echo_mixed_risk_record-2, topic_wh_sparkstream_echo_mixed_risk_record-0]
19/07/22 11:30:00 INFO internals.AbstractCoordinator: [Consumer clientId=consumer-4, groupId=dashboard] (Re-)joining group
19/07/22 11:30:00 INFO internals.AbstractCoordinator: [Consumer clientId=consumer-4, groupId=dashboard] Marking the coordinator 10.124.35.112:9092 (id: 2147483534 rack: null) dead
19/07/22 11:30:00 INFO internals.AbstractCoordinator: [Consumer clientId=consumer-4, groupId=dashboard] Discovered group coordinator 10.124.35.112:9092 (id: 2147483534 rack: null)
19/07/22 11:30:00 INFO internals.AbstractCoordinator: [Consumer clientId=consumer-4, groupId=dashboard] (Re-)joining group
19/07/22 11:35:00 INFO internals.AbstractCoordinator: [Consumer clientId=consumer-4, groupId=dashboard] Successfully joined group with generation 822
19/07/22 11:35:00 INFO internals.ConsumerCoordinator: [Consumer clientId=consumer-4, groupId=dashboard] Setting newly assigned partitions [topic_wh_sparkstream_echo_mixed_risk_record-1, topic_wh_sparkstream_echo_mixed_risk_record-2, topic_wh_sparkstream_echo_mixed_risk_record-0]
19/07/22 11:35:00 INFO dstream.MappedDStream: Slicing from 1563765000000 ms to 1563765600000 ms (aligned to 1563765000000 ms and 1563765600000 ms)
19/07/22 11:35:00 INFO internals.ConsumerCoordinator: [Consumer clientId=consumer-3, groupId=dashboard] Revoking previously assigned partitions [topic_wh_sparkstream_echo_mixed_risk_result_detail-2, topic_wh_sparkstream_echo_mixed_risk_result_detail-1, topic_wh_sparkstream_echo_mixed_risk_result_detail-0, topic_wh_sparkstream_echo_behavior_features_result-0, topic_wh_sparkstream_echo_behavior_features_result-1, topic_wh_sparkstream_echo_behavior_features_result-2]
19/07/22 11:35:00 INFO internals.AbstractCoordinator: [Consumer clientId=consumer-3, groupId=dashboard] (Re-)joining group
19/07/22 11:35:00 INFO internals.AbstractCoordinator: [Consumer clientId=consumer-3, groupId=dashboard] Marking the coordinator 10.124.35.112:9092 (id: 2147483534 rack: null) dead
19/07/22 11:35:00 INFO internals.AbstractCoordinator: [Consumer clientId=consumer-3, groupId=dashboard] Discovered group coordinator 10.124.35.112:9092 (id: 2147483534 rack: null)
19/07/22 11:35:00 INFO internals.AbstractCoordinator: [Consumer clientId=consumer-3, groupId=dashboard] (Re-)joining group
```

at the window timestamp, only do kafka re-partitions instead of add a job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this problem.
Use spark-Streaming with kafka, congfig each stream with separate group_id and disable auto-commit,
Config kafka parameters appropriate. Especially heartbeat, session-timeout, request-timesout, max-poll-interval.